# Example to store pointer in extra window memory of window class

Tags: winapi

I have a class that represents a text box, in the constructor of the class I call the `CreateWindow` function, and I want to store in the extra window memory, pointer to this object, so in the `WndProc` function I will get the pointer, and will use the class members.
I tried to do that with this code, but it's not working, can someone to write an example how to do this:

- What value should I give in `cbWndExtra` member of `WNDCLASSEX` structure.
- How to call `SetWindowLong`.
- How to call `GetWindowLong`.

the code I wrote:

```
  wcex.cbWndExtra   = 4;
```

and I wrote this in the constructor of the text box class:

```
  hWnd = CreateWindow(...);
  SetWindowLong(hWnd,0,(LONG)this);
```

and this in the `WndProc` function

```
  unique_ptr<TextBox> pTextBox;
  pTextBox.reset((TextBox*)GetWindowLong(hWnd,0));
```

===   edit   ===

now I see that if I change the code in the `WndProc` function, to this code:

```
 TextBox *pTextBox;
 pTextBox = (TextBox*)GetWindowLong(hWnd,0);
```

it work as well, but with `unique_ptr` it do not work.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: Note that SetWindowLong only stores a long, not a pointer. On 64 bit platforms those are not the same.

Comment: @Robert - I do not get the object of this class, jast new object.

Comment: Except for @Billy ONeal's point about not working on 64 bit I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Could you add the class registration call and the full CreateWindow()?

Comment: @HerrJoebob - see my edit of question.

Comment: To support 64-bit, you have to use `Get/SetWindowLongPtr()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN Documentation on "SetWindowLong", about the 'Index' parameter.

> The zero-based offset to the value to be set. Valid values are in the range zero through the number of bytes of extra window memory, minus the size of an integer. To set any other value, specify one of the following values.

Positive offsets can point to any byte offset so long as you created the window with at least that amount of "cbWndExtra" in the WNDCLASS structure.

I suspect the issue in this case may be related to the size of the pointer. You are explicitly allocating 4 extra bytes to the end of the window structure, but if you are on a 64-bit system, the pointer size would be 8. This could explain it sometimes working, and sometimes not. (If the high order word happens to be all zeros, it may work even though the address is being truncated.) 
If this is the case, you would need to either set the high and low word in two separate calls, or preferably use the 64-bit variant "SetWindowLongPtr".

Here's a simple example that uses this feature to store two pointers in a windows extra data region (Note the following will work with both 32 and 64 bit)

```
wndclass.cbWndExtra = sizeof(char*) * 2; // Reserve space for 2 pointers.
```

Then later set a values with:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0, (LONG_PTR)firstPtr);
SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, sizeof(char*), (LONG_PTR)secondPtr); // Index is byte offset.
```

And retrieve the values with:

```
LONG_PTR firstPtr = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, 0);
LONG_PTR secondPtr = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, sizeof(char*));
```

If you only need to store one single pointer however, you can get away with not setting any extra memory, leave cbWndExtra at zero, and just pass GWLP_USERDATA as the index. Like the other pre-defined values, GWLP_USERDATA is a negative offset 'backwards' into the class/window data. It is reserved space for this kind of purpose, but it can only fit one pointers worth of data.