# How to access the custom class members from a call back method

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2013, callback, djvu

I want to access the members of a custom class from callback method.

I am accessing  `m_displayImg->bIsPressAndHold = true;` from  call back functions.

i.e.

It gives error "Identifier M_displayImg is undefined".

```
class CDisplayImage
{
public:
    CDisplayImage(void);
    virtual ~CDisplayImage(void);

    int Initialize(HWND hWnd, CDC* dc, IUnknown* controller);
    void Uninitialize(int context);
    BOOL bIsPressAndHold = false;
    //code omitted
};


VOID CALLBACK DoCircuitHighlighting(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    m_displayImg->bIsPressAndHold = true;       
   // I have omitted code for simplicity.
}
```

How can I access that custom class member?

Comment: Firstly, see [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Secondly: the typical way to slip parameters (e.g. an associated class) to windows callbacks without using global variables is to [put them in the HWND's GWL_USERDATA field](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14883556/211160).

Comment: @HostileFork Sir, I have modified the question.

Comment: The [code you added](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41820817/2) isn't particularly relevant, because it doesn't show the class which contains `m_displayImg` or `m_startPoint`.  It's *that* class that you would want to associate with the HWND, presumably.  Whatever that class is, it's the one where you would save its pointer in the GWL_USERDATA of the HWND (when it gets its HWND created or passed in), and then extract the pointer from the `hwnd` parameter of DoCircuitHighlighting when that is called.

Comment: @HostileFork Basically DoCircuitHighlighting is performing some actions on the objects of another class named "CDjVuControlCtrl". Which I have omitted for the simplicity.

Comment: If you want code you can apply, you have to give an appropriate MCVE. Else all I can say is that the mechanical problem you have is that plain C functions are not member functions--they have no "this" pointer.  And you can't pass a member function [or a std::function wrapping a class and a member function together](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and use it in places where a plain C callback is needed.  You need either a global variable to access the related class through, or a way to get it from the hwnd--which I linked you how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously i encountered a similar problem. I solved it with namespaced variable, because CALLBACK function cannot accept more parameters, you cannot even put anything in lambda capture list.

My code sample (different content, but the idea remains the same):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace MonitorInfo {
    // namespace variable
    extern std::vector<MONITORINFOEX> data = std::vector<MONITORINFOEX>();

    // callback function
    BOOL CALLBACK callbackFunction(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) {
        MONITORINFOEX monitorInfo;
        monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(monitorInfo);
        GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monitorInfo);
        data.push_back(monitorInfo);
        return true;
    }

    // get all monitors data
    std::vector<MONITORINFOEX> get(){
        data.clear();
        EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, callbackFunction, 0);
        return data;
    }
};

int main(){
    auto info = MonitorInfo::get();
    printf("%d", info.size());
    return 0;
}
```