# How does a single wndproc let each window know its serial number?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

```
int Num = 0;
LRESULT CALLBACK TestWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
    RECT Winrc;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &Winrc);
    SYSTEMTIME time;
    GetLocalTime(&time);
    static const wchar_t* BoxTxt = L"";
    static int MeIs = Num;
    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE,
            GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 220, LWA_ALPHA);
        //GhWnd = hWnd;
        break;
    }
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
            wchar_t meChar[20] = L"";
            _itow(MeIs, meChar, 10);
            MessageBox(0, meChar, meChar, 0);
    }
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rc, 1);
        break;
    }
    case WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK:
    {
        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        switch (wmId)
        {

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        Num -= 1;
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
int CreateTestWindow()
{
//Call testwndproc. To reduce the length of the problem description, omit these codes
Num+=1;
return 0;
}
```

In the above code, when I create multiple windows and click it, it should pop up "1", "2", "3"... But actually all pop up "1".

```
static int MeIs = 0;
case WM_CREATE:
{
MeIs = Num;
}
```

Change to the above code and the serial number of the last window will pop up. For example, when the fourth window is created, all windows will pop up "4"

In practical application, each window has its own settings and is stored in the vector. Each window finds its own settings according to its own serial number:

```
struct Data
{
int x;
int y;
int width;
int height;
const wchar_t* text;
}
std::vector<data>UserData(32);//Max:32
//then read them from file,But the window must know which window it is:UserData[i].
```

For example,the first window will set their coordinates to UserData[1].x and UserData[1].y,also need to save the file when closing.
Any idea?thank you!

Comment: `static int MeIs` - you get just one of these in the program, not one per-window. If you want per-window data you can add storage space when you register your window class.

Comment: But how to  add storage space?I want each window data to be independent, but there is only one WndProc.

Comment: You should read Petzold's book. It's really not going to be productive tryjng to learn like this.

Comment: [`cbWndExtra`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexa).

Comment: isn't `hwnd` already indicate window?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to maintain per-window data using the Win32 API.

The simplest is using the `GWL_USERDATA` slot accessible via `GetWindowLongPtr(...)` and `SetWindowLongPtr(...)`. A typical way to initialize this user data value is to use the creation parameters passed to the `WM_CREATE` message by the `CreateWindow` call.

Code below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

struct SomeData {
    int n;
    std::wstring str;
};

int RegisterWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, const wchar_t* wnd_class) {
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszClassName = wnd_class;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int CreateWindowWithUserData(HINSTANCE hInstance, const wchar_t* wnd_class, int n, const std::wstring& str) {
    auto* data_ptr = new SomeData{ n, str };

    if (!CreateWindow(wnd_class,  L"Window text",  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,  0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, data_ptr))
        return 2;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const auto* wnd_class = L"foobar";
    RegisterWindow(hInstance, wnd_class);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        CreateWindowWithUserData(hInstance, wnd_class, i, L"blah");
    }
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: {
            CREATESTRUCT* create_struct = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam);
            SomeData* user_data = reinterpret_cast<SomeData*>(create_struct->lpCreateParams);
            SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG>(user_data));
        } 
        return 0;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT: {
        SomeData* user_data = reinterpret_cast<SomeData*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        RECT r = { 20, 20, 300, 35 };
        auto msg = user_data->str + L" " + std::to_wstring(user_data->n);
        DrawText(hdc, msg.c_str(), -1, &r, DT_SINGLELINE);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY: {
        SomeData* user_data = reinterpret_cast<SomeData*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
        delete user_data;
        }
        return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Another way to do something similar is to use the `cbWndExtra` extra field when registering the window class, [as discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44883141/1413244).

Comment: Thank you, but there is another problem. If a window is closed, how do I inform the program to reorder all windows?
For example, if I close the second window (assuming there are five in total), the third window will be sorted as "2", and so on

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. They are separate windows . The user can put them in whatever order the user wants. But they will still display the correct per-window data they were created with.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear. It means that a total of windows with serial numbers of 1, 2, 3, 4,5 are created, but for example, if the window with serial number of 3 is closed, use the later window serial number to supplement the closed window, like 4 becomes 3, 5 becomes 4. Is there a way to realize it? Thank you for your hard work.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Indeed store data in Window. `SetProp`, `SetWindowLong`+`GWL_USERDATA`, `SetWindowLong`+`cbWndExtra`
- Map HWND to your data, like using c++ `std::map`
- Use a thunk to have an associated object, like ATL, see [ATL thunk header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/atlthunk/) for available APIs (have to do it manually for older OSes)